# Find the center of a sphere from 2 points, a radius, and a known condition

Tags: spherical-trigonometry

I have $2$ arbitrary points in space, $p_1$ and $p_2$, that both lie on a sphere of known radius $r$.

The center of the sphere is such that if a line were drawn around the sphere through both points $p_1$ and $p_2$, the line would also cross through the bottom most point of the sphere and would create a slice of the sphere of the maximum size circle.

How can I find the center of the sphere $p$? And the equation that defines the circle that would represent the line drawn around it?

Comment: Define what “the bottom most point of the sphere” is, please.

Comment: Sure. The bottom most point is the point of the sphere with the smallest y value. Y being the axis representing up/down in my scenario. So a sphere of radius 1, at origin, the bottom most point would be 0,-1,0. Given my other condition of "maximum size circle" this also means my circle would cross through the top most point of the sphere, or 0,1,0 in my example here.